# Jersey web service with date or primitive as parameter

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have a jersey web service that takes post data and maps it (using jackson) to a data structure that looks like

```
public class MyObject {   
   String name
   Object dateOrPrimitive    
}
```

On the javascript client that calls the web service, it could send an object that could take either of the following forms

```
{ name : "Jeff", dateOrPrimitive : "someOtherString" } 
{ name : "Jeff", dateOrPrimitive : new Date() }
```

If the `dateOrPrimitive` field has a date in it, it is deserialized into a string representation of the date. But what I would like to do is deserialize it to a date if it is a valid date string.

I wrote a custom deserializer that checks if the value is a valid date and returns a date if it is and a primitive otherwise, but I was wondering if there is already a built in a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't such a thing in Jackson. Your custom deserializer is the way to go on this. Personnaly I would have two different properties, one a Date and the other a primitive, but I'm guessing you don't have control over the format of the Json.

Comment: In this case I can't change the underlying java object that the json is being mapped to (I could change the json itself but without changing the java object that wouldn't really help).